# Why does my code stop when populating cells in a datatable?

Tags: c#, database, datatable, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I'm trying to write specific cell data from an accessDatabase into a datatable. I get this data using SELECT queries, but when writing the data to a specific cell in the datatable the loop breaks before iteration through even once, when it should iterate through twice.

Here's the code I'm using :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  // Creates Table
dt.Clear();

dt.Columns.Add("Hol/Abs", typeof(string));      // Column 0  
dt.Columns.Add("FirstDay", typeof(DateTime));   // Column 1 
dt.Columns.Add("LastDay", typeof(DateTime));    // Column 2
dt.Columns.Add("TotalDays", typeof(int));       // Column 3
dt.Columns.Add("Reason", typeof(string));       // Column 4

LblName.Text = PassName; //Loads Name

string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo FROM [Employee] WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = @Name";
string CountQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Holiday]";
        string GetStartQuery = "SELECT StartDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
        string GetEndQuery = "SELECT EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
        string GetReasonQuery = "SELECT Reason FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        using (OleDbCommand GetPayroll = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn))            
        {
            conn.Open();                
            GetPayroll.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LblName.Text;
            int GotPayroll = Convert.ToInt32(GetPayroll.ExecuteScalar());   //Uses Query to Get PayrollNo
            OleDbCommand CountRowsInHol = new OleDbCommand(CountQuery, conn);
            CountRowsInHol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
            int HolidayCount = (int) (CountRowsInHol.ExecuteScalar()); //Uses CountQuery to Get HowMany lines are in [Holiday] 
            int LoopCount = 0;
            while (LoopCount <= HolidayCount) //Will go though all Lines in [Holiday]
            {                    
                OleDbCommand GetStart = new OleDbCommand(GetStartQuery, conn);
                OleDbCommand GetEnd = new OleDbCommand(GetEndQuery, conn);
                OleDbCommand GetReason = new OleDbCommand(GetReasonQuery, conn);
                GetStart.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;

                GetEnd.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
                GetReason.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
                DateTime StartHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetStart.ExecuteScalar());
                DateTime EndHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetEnd.ExecuteScalar());
                string ReasonHold = (GetReason.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
                dt.Rows[LoopCount]["FirstDay"] = StartHold;
                dt.Rows[LoopCount]["LastDay"] = EndHold;
                dt.Rows[LoopCount]["Reason"] = ReasonHold;
                LoopCount = LoopCount + 1;
            }
        }
```

I know its long but it's pretty basic. The code breaks at ..

> dt.Rows[LoopCount]["FirstDay"] = StartHold;

..instead of writing to the datatable.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, also I'm very open to clear advice regarding formatting my code better so it's easier to read and more universally standard.

Comment: I don't see that you ever fill the data table with rows. A good practice is to wrap your code in `Try/Catch` and read the exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Help, CrowCoder put me in the right direction. I NEVER ADDED ROWS! Using this code everything works brilliant so hopefully other noobie coders wont get stuck for as long as me!

Replaced from **dt.rows[LoopCount]** with the following

```
DataRow NewLine = dt.NewRow();
NewLine["Hol/Abs"] = "Holiday";
NewLine["FirstDay"] = StartHold;
NewLine["LastDay"] = EndHold;
NewLine["TotalDays"] = (EndHold - StartHold);
NewLine["Reason"] = ReasonHold;
dt.Rows.Add(NewLine);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure, but could it be a small mistake as replacing:

```
dt.Rows[LoopCount]["FirstDay"] = StartHold;
```

with:

```
dt.Rows[LoopCount].["FirstDay"] = StartHold;
```

Maybe I am wrong but just want to know if say dt.Rows[0] contains the field ["FirstDay"].